# Page Object Pattern with Selenium and Testng failure

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng, pom.xml

I am having issue running the below Page Object Model with testng.

TestClass 1

```
package Proj;

public class signInPage {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
      ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
        public signInPage (WebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver=driver;
        }

        WebDriver driver;
        public signInPage() 
        {
            driver.get("baseURL");

        }

        By Email_address = By.name("Username");
        By Password = By.id("Password");

        public WebElement Email_address () 
        {
        return driver.findElement(Email_address);
        }

        public WebElement Password ()
        {
            return driver.findElement(Password);
        }
       public WebElement button_id () 
    {
    return driver.findElement(button_id);
    }
}
```

TestClass 2

```
package Proj;

public class MyDetailsPage {

    public MyDetailsPage (WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    WebDriver driver;

    By My_Details=By.xpath(".//*[@id='masterForm']/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[3]/a/span");
    By First_name = By.id("FirstName"); 
    By  Last_name= By.name("NameModel.LastName");
    By button_id= By.id("stage_one_button");

    public WebElement My_Details () 
    {
    return driver.findElement(My_Details);
    }

    public WebElement First_name () 
    {
    return driver.findElement(First_name);
    }

    public WebElement Last_name () 
    {
    return driver.findElement(Last_name);
    }
    }
```

TestData Page

```
 package Proj;



    public class testData  {

        public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
              ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    }

        public void testDetails (WebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver=driver;
        }
            static WebDriver driver;


               protected static String baseUrl;
               protected static String Email_address;
               protected static String Password;
               protected String First_name;
               protected String Last_name;

        public void Data () {
                 baseUrl = "https://login.yahoo.com/";
                 driver = new ChromeDriver();
                 Email_address = "myname@yahoo.com";
                 Password = "myname";
                 First_name = "Testing";
                 Last_name = "Account";

        }
         }
```

TestCases

```
package Proj;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;


public class TestCases extends testData {

    private static SearchContext WebElement;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void BeforeSuite () {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();    

    }

     @BeforeClass 
    public void driver(WebDriver driver)  throws InterruptedException

            {
               this.driver = driver;
                driver.get(baseUrl);    
            }

      @Test
     public void AllTest () throws InterruptedException {
        signInPage a = new signInPage (driver);
        a.Email_address().sendKeys(Email_address);
        a.Password().sendKeys(Password);
        a.SIGN_IN().click();

        MyDetailsPage e = new MyDetailsPage (driver);       
        e.My_Details ().click();
        e.First_name ().sendKeys("Testing");
        e.Last_name (). sendKeys ("Account");
        e.button_id ().click();     

        }
        }
```

It opens up Browser but fail to enter baseUrl and could not perform the Test. It is failing from the TestCases class. No matter how i have tried to reconfigure this with no luck. I appreciate your prompt assistance. Thank you

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass driver
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a BeforeClass annotated driver.
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:244)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:118)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:206)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

SKIPPED: AllTest
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a BeforeClass annotated driver.
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:244)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:118)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:206)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


    ===============================================
    Default suite
    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================
```

Answer (score 1):

`public void driver(WebDriver driver)` is not allowed on a `@BeforeClass` method. You have to remove the parameter and find another way to set the `driver`.

Comment: I have already remove (WebDriver driver) in the public void driver(WebDriver driver) and still experience the same issue - browser opens but didnt perform any actions.

Answer (score 1):

As juherr pointed out that you can not parameterize the @BeforeClass in this manner by passing webdriver instead you can follow following approach to do so:

```
public class TestCases extends testData {

private static SearchContext WebElement;
WebDriver driver;


@BeforeSuite
public void BeforeSuite () throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Eclipse\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

}

@BeforeClass 
public void driver()  throws InterruptedException
{
    driver = new ChromeDriver ();    

    testData td = new testData ();

    driver.get(td.baseUrl);    
}
/
/
/
/
```

Comment: I have done as suggested and my getting this error - FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass driver
java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null

Comment: you need to define baseURL value as   `baseUrl = "https://login.yahoo.com/";` in your TestCases class

Comment: I have already define the URL in my TestData Page. I followed your suggestion and defined the URL in TestCases. It opens up the Web and didn't perform the actions.

Comment: yes, but that is not accessible within the TestCases  class, you have to provide a way forbaseUrl to be accessible

Comment: i have done that and its still not performing the actions.

Comment: Although it would have been better if you kept your data() content inside a testData constructor.

Comment: I have tried it again and am getting - FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod openUrl
java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                          And how am i suppose to keep the data() content inside a testData constructor. Thanks

Comment: just change this `public void Data () ` statement to `public testData ()`

Comment: Hi Kusahl, i have done that and still no luck. It opens up browser and does not enter Url.

Comment: Now that you have changed your data() function to testData Condtructor, then make use of my updated code.